# Fastest way to find the greatest 1st and 2nd items of a list of tuples simultaneously in python

Tags: python

I was fiddling around with lists of tuples and I was wondering, what would be the fastest way to grab the greatest 1st and 2nd values from the list of tuples simultaneously? For example assume we have a list of tuples like so:

```
_list = [(0, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 4)]
```

The max first value is 3 and the max second value is 4, therefore I would like to get the tuple `(3, 4)`. What might be the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
(max(a[0] for a in list), max(a[1] for a in list))
```

Comment: No need to use lists, use generator expressions instead.

Comment: @Octopus Get rid of the square brackets. Leave everything else as it is.

Comment: My tests (via `timeit`) showed that this is slightly slower than aj8uppal's answer (this showed `1.1484151073659632e-05` seconds on average whereas his showed `9.889130097917587e-06` seconds on average).

Comment: @Octopus As originally posted, there were additional square brackets within the function calls to `max()`. Those are not necessary.

Comment: Nevermind, apparently this runs slightly faster than aj8uppal's answer for larger amounts of items (+100000 items).

Comment: @user3002473 According to my timings, it's still ~50% slower than using my proposed solution.

Answer (score 4):

After timing the various scripts posted here (with list length of 10000), the fastest version is a traditional for loop:

```
mi = mj = float('-inf')
for i, j in lst:
    if i > mi:
        mi = i
    if j > mj:
        mj = j
print mi, mj
```

But the prettiest has to be by using zip:

```
lst = [(0, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 4)]
print tuple(max(x) for x in zip(*lst))
# -> (3, 4)
```

**Timings (on Python 2.7.1):**

```
Function        Time    Performance
max_for2(lst):  0.9241  100%
max_izip(lst):  1.3093  141%
max_for1(lst):  1.3596  147%
max_zip(lst):   1.4750  159%
max_gen(lst):   2.1235  229%
```

**Timing code:**

```
setup = '''
from itertools import izip
from random import randint

def max_zip(lst):
    return tuple(max(x) for x in zip(*lst))

def max_izip(lst):
    return tuple(max(x) for x in izip(*lst))

def max_gen(lst):
    return max(a[0] for a in lst), max(a[1] for a in lst)

def max_for1(lst):
    mi = mj = float('-inf')
    for i, j in lst:
        mi = i if i > mi else mi
        mj = j if j > mj else mj

    return mi, mj

def max_for2(lst):
    mi = mj = float('-inf')
    for i, j in lst:
        if i > mi:
            mi = i
        if j > mj:
            mj = j

    return mi, mj

lst = [(randint(0, 10000), randint(0, 10000)) for _ in xrange(10000)]
'''

from timeit import timeit

statements= (
    'max_zip(lst)',
    'max_izip(lst)',
    'max_gen(lst)',
    'max_for1(lst)',
    'max_for2(lst)'
)

timings = {}

for stmt in statements:
    timings[stmt] = timeit(stmt=stmt, setup=setup, number=1000)

print 'Function\t\tTime\tPerformance'
for key, value in sorted(timings.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print '{}:\t{:.4f}\t{}%'.format(
        key, value, int(100*value/min(timings.values())))
```

Comment: Yours is indeed the prettiest.

Comment: Curious, I went to find out how to do the equivalent in Clojure: it is `(apply mapv max lst)`.

Comment: I'd start with `mx = mn = float('-inf')` then loop over `for i, j in lst:` (e.g. no slicing). Saves a list copy operation. Oh, and use `mi` and `mj` for names, `mx` and `mn` imply you are looking for a maximum and minimum instead of two maximi.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your input, I've implemented it.

Comment: Nice to see that that indeed squeezes out some more speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mx = []
>>> mn = []
>>> for i, j in _list:
...     mx.append(i)
...     mn.append(j)
...
>>> x = (max(mx), max(mn))
>>> x
(3, 4)
```

Append each value to a list, and then get the maximum. From that, create a tuple.

Comment: Surprisingly enough this seems to be the fastest method for my purposes, thanks!

Comment: Remember to accept an answer which answered your question after 15 minutes :), and thanks!

Comment: Sorry aj8uppal, I just ran some tests on lists of +100000 items and found that Octopus' answer was more efficient.

Comment: Yep, I thought so: I was taken aback when you said mine was faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this. :)

```
max(lst)[0], max(lst, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
```

Time:

```
>>> %timeit max(lst)[0],max(lst, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 us per loop

    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023689/2931409
>>> %timeit (max(a[0] for a in lst), max(a[1] for a in lst))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 us per loop

    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023736/2931409
>>> %timeit tuple(max(x) for x in itertools.izip(*lst))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 us per loop
```